# Esclarecer ou fazer o trabalho pelos outros?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Tenho me deparado aqui com uma diferença para o [stackoverflow.com](http://stackoverflow.com), aqui o pessoal **pergunta mesmo antes de pesquisar** seja onde for. 
*A ideia é ser uma ajuda para possíveis problemas, ou fazer o trabalho de casa pelos outros?*
Temos aqui [um exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11608/fim-de-entrada-scanner-java/11609?noredirect=1#comment20023_11609) e mais [outro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11622/problema-com-conversao-de-codigo-c).
E aqui um [bom exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10847/por-que-o-atributo-gravity-do-objeto-linearlayout-layoutparams-nao-funciona-como/11554?noredirect=1#comment19936_11554) do que considero boa prática.

[EDIT]

Eu por exemplo agora preciso de saber algumas informações sobre sessões em PHP, como por exemplo o tempo de sessão, etc.

A primeira coisa que fiz foi pesquisar encontrei este site:
[sessões em php](http://www.revistaphp.com.br/artigo.php?id=79).
A pergunta que fica é, deveria eu ter pesquisado primeiro? Ou seria melhor ter logo perguntado no SOPT para que todos tivessem acesso a essa resposta?

É preciso definir muito bem este tipo de coisas.

Um exemplo que vi agora que acho é [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11740/como-criar-um-array-infinito) que demonstra uma falta de pesquisa, uma pergunta muito ampla e, mal explicada. Pode levar a várias interpretações:

- Será que fez algum tipo de pesquisa?
- Será que tem de ser mesmo o tipo array[] ou poderá ser um ArrayList?
- Será infinito ou indefinido ou os dois?
- Isso não será demasiado básico, sem contexto?

Podem dar a vossa opinião, a minha é que ficava já marcada como demasiado ampla.

Como podem ver agora até tem uma resposta bem estruturada, um grande resposta. Mas será que isso não é incentivar os "faz me isto"?

[/EDIT]

Comment: Relacionada: [O que fazer com usuários que estão na zona de conforto?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1137/3117)

Comment: Acho que um *mínimo de demonstração de esforços de pesquisa* é um **sinal de respeito pelo tempo alheio**.

Comment: [Pergunta relacionada](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/105/215). Estritamente falando, se a pergunta for clara, objetiva e de escopo restrito, não é **necessário** demonstrar esforço, mas é **de bom tom** (respeito pelo tempo alheio, como bem colocado por brasofilo). E, claro, cada um decide que tipo de pergunta merece sua atenção - de modo que se uma pergunta não lhe parece útil, há sempre a opção de ignorá-la. Eu normalmente reservo meus downvotes para casos *gritantes* de "faça meu trabalho pra mim", e as demais acabam muitas vezes caindo em "amplo demais" ou "pergunta não está clara".

Comment: A pergunta que fica no ar também é como proceder se acharmos que alguém está a tentar que façam o trabalho por ele?

Comment: Eu lembro que o SO original não permite comentários com links pro `Let Me Google That For You`. Não concordo com esse bloqueio lá... Não sei se é bloqueado aqui também, mas espero que não seja. LMGTFY é uma mensagem clara e direta pra quem terceiriza trabalho de pesquisa básica pra cá.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Nem, nem outro. Pelo que entendo do site, a ideia é construir uma base de conhecimento que possa beneficiar o maior número de pessoas.

Classificar uma pergunta como "lição de casa" é uma questão muitas vezes subjetiva. Cada um tem um nível de conhecimento e especialidades em áreas diferentes. Algo simples pode ser muito complicado para iniciantes em programação. Para alguns é fácil pesquisar conteúdo existente em Inglês, mas se todo desenvolvedor fosse proficiente em outras línguas não precisaríamos deste site para começo de conversa.

Além disso, se a questão for mal formulada ou sofrer de algum mal intrínseco, os usuários irão votar contra ela, solicitar a edição, o fechamento ou até mesmo a exclusão.

Se você está se referindo à pergunta [Fim de entrada Scanner Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11608/fim-de-entrada-scanner-java), não vejo graves problemas com ela. É uma pergunta sobre programação e o autor exemplificou com um código próprio. O que talvez não ficou bem definido é a questão da tecla <kbd>CTRL+Z</kbd>. Ao que me parece o autor quer simular o mesmo comportamento que o comando `scanf` do C. Isso é tão trivial assim?

Vou comentar algo sobre sua resposta:

> Acho que o melhor mesmo era estudar um bocadinho java

Suponha que um estudante de faculdade teve contato apenas com C em suas aulas e tem conhecimentos bem superficiais sobre programação. Você acha mesmo que ele conseguiria se virar para converter um código C para Java sem ajuda?

> até porque a API é muito boa e explica direitinho...

A API do Java deixa muito a desejar em vários aspectos. Melhorou nos últimos anos, mas, sinceramente, ninguém merece ficar lendo JavaDocs. 99% das vezes eu e as pessoas que conheço preferem outras fontes de estudo, incluindo o Stack Overflow. Além do mais, você não se torna um bom programador Java com a API, isso exige a leitura de muitos livros, tanto que indicações como Effective Java, Head First e cia. são unânimes nos fóruns.

> A ideia aqui é esclarecer possíveis dúvidas e não fazer o trabalho pelos outros. Certo?

Concordo com o que você disse, mas não com a certeza que você tem de que o OP estava pedindo para fazer o trabalho de casa. Como já mencionei, ele pode nem saber por onde começar, então seria mais construtivo dar uma direção inicial para ele poder então pesquisar.

Enfim, termino meus comentários observando que muitos desenvolvedores programam errado justamente porque eles não aprendem com pessoas mais experientes. Mandamos eles "se virarem" sem dar pelo menos uma direção e acabam cheios de vícios e práticas duvidosas.

Comment: Se a ideia do site é essa tudo muito bem, mas acho um bocado mau vir pedir ajuda. Como faço isto? Sem sequer demonstrar que tentou, ou que leu alguma coisa sobre o assunto. 
Qualquer dia venho aqui. Alguém me poderia ajudar a fazer o algoritmo de Dijkstra em C e em Java? Se eu não tentar como vou aprender. Eu uso este site versão .com para me ajudar quando não consigo fazer de outra forma. Senão primeiro estudo e vejo exemplos existentes.

Comment: É trivial sim fazer isso. Esse senhor da pergunta aprendeu o que com aquilo? Nada, aprendeu a vir para aqui pedir ajuda para tudo sem tentar nada, porque não demonstrou que tentou. Isto claro é a minha opinião.

Comment: @JorgeB. `É trivial sim fazer isso`, se você estiver se referindo ao Ctrl+Z eu diria que não é trivial não, eu sou programador Java e não sei fazer isso. Talvez o autor da pergunta não aprenda nada, mas eu aprenderia.

Comment: @Math Pois é, eu também não sabia. Lógico que já pesquisei em Inglês e descobri que realmente é trivial. O problema é que essa é uma questão do sistema operacional e não do Java. No linux, por exemplo a tecla é `CTRL+D`.

Comment: @Math Mas é mesmo esse o caso, a forma como é formulada a pergunta. Se fosse formulada doutra forma, demonstrar que está interessado em aprender e não "façam me isto".

Comment: @JorgeB. O usuário que faz a pergunta havia se cadastrado no site a apenas alguns minutos. Teria sido melhor pedir perguntar o que ele já tinha feito ao invés de simplesmente mandar ele estudar mais. Paciência é uma virtude.

Comment: @utluiz pois então que seja trivial, mas ninguém sabe. Temos que procurar em inglês para encontrar a solução então? E em português, não teremos isso nunca? (não estou dizendo que vc está discordando de mim)

Comment: @utluiz Nisso tens razão, precipitei-me um bocado. De qualquer forma já vi isso é muitos lados como resposta. Principalmente no `.com`. Mas lá é imediatamente sinalizada.

Comment: @JorgeB. acho que é quase o mesmo caso, não chega a ser aquele exemplo q eu dei na resposta, um exemplo de alguém que só passa os requisitos e pede o sitema seria o [Programa do Labirinto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11316/3117) (que eu mesmo votei para fechar). Nesse caso de hoje, a pessoa não pede um sistema, pede um comando, a resposta pode ser dada em algumas linha, cabe até num comentário, diferente da resposta do labirinto. Minha opinião.

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, o SO.com realmente funciona de maneira bem diferente do SOPT, mas lembre-se que [Aqui não é o SO.com](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1/3117). Eu mesmo já me senti inibido de perguntar as coisas no SO.com, não acho o povo de lá muito solícito, talvez sejam características da cultura, seila.

Comment: @Math eu sei disso. De qualquer forma acho que não custava nada explicar melhor o problema. Do género [disto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10847/por-que-o-atributo-gravity-do-objeto-linearlayout-layoutparams-nao-funciona-como/11554?noredirect=1#comment19936_11554)
Aqui claramente se verifica que houve trabalho de casa, mas sem sucesso. Não sei me estou a conseguir fazer entender.

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, entendi seu ponto de vista, as vezes eu tb acho que existem muitas pessoas preguiçosas que fazem pergunta sem um minimo de pesquisa antes (não acho que tenha sido o caso agora). Nesses casos, se a resposta for simples e objetiva (e eu souber) eu respondo, se for gigante eu sinalizo, se for meio termo eu passo a bola.

Comment: @Math aqui outro [exemplo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11622/problema-com-conversao-de-codigo-c) de falta dum mínimo de pesquisa.
Pelo menos eu acho que é incentivar as pessoas virem aqui postarem tudo e mais alguma coisa sem sequer estudar ou tentar resolver.

Comment: @JorgeB. sim, devemos incentivar as pessoas a fazer perguntas de qualidade, mas talvez o próprio sistema de votação já faça isso, repare que nesse seu último link a maior pontuação foi de `1`, tanto para a pergunta como para as respostas. Entretanto, ser grosso com uma pessoa ao invés de incentivá-la pode afastá-la do site, e não é o que queremos.

Comment: @Math Sim nisso já tinha dito que têm razão.

Comment: Tenho, agora, uma ideia completamente diferente passado quase um ano.