# Vampiro de Ajuda : Pergunta -> 26175

Tags: suporte, pergunta-específica

[Neste comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/26175/manipulando-links-com-acentos/26241#comment48800_26241) o autor da pergunta, após ler a minha resposta e viu que não estava pronta para encaixar no script que ele copiou. Disse claramente:

> Não sei como fazer isso (...)

E adaptou a sua pergunta para que *alguém possivelmente veja o código e o adapte para ele*.

A pergunta original não era tão ruim (nem boa - considero-a praticamente que beirando o aceitável). Mas ao ver perguntas tratanto do tema aqui no Meta como:

[O problema dos Vampiros de Ajuda](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1160/o-problema-dos-vampiros-de-ajuda)

> Esperam clara, óbvia e despreocupadamente que alguma pobre, bem-intencionada, pessoa faça toda a análise pra eles?

e
[Esclarecer ou fazer o trabalho pelos outros?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157/esclarecer-ou-fazer-o-trabalho-pelos-outros/1158#1158)

> A ideia aqui é esclarecer possíveis dúvidas e não fazer o trabalho pelos outros. Certo?
>   Fiquei com uma dúvida sobre o meu posicionamento:

Como usuário você deve reportar (de alguma forma) o comportamento desses **vampiros** ou apenas torcer para que eles entendam o recado deixando comentários e agir-se-ão melhor no futuro?

Nota: penso que por sermos uma comunidade menor que o SOEN temos mais capacidade de controlar e evitar esse tipo de *"ataque"*.

Comment: Infelizmente isso acontece muito, mas muitas vezes são perguntas interessantes, que acabam por ficarem excelentes com uma resposta muito boa. Eu tento não fazer o trabalho pelos outros, e dar orientações, mas acaba sempre alguém a responder com o trabalho feito.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Como usuário você deve reportar (de alguma forma) o comportamento desses vampiros ou apenas torcer para que eles entendam o recado deixando comentários e agir-se-ão melhor no futuro?

"Agir-se-ão"? :) Você pode:

- Deixar um comentário instrutivo
- Simplesmente ignorar o usuário

Em qualquer um desses casos, se o comportamento de "vampiro" for repetitivo, sinalize um dos posts para atenção dos moderadores, e explique o que está acontecendo. Os moderadores podem decidir entrar em contato com o usuário e instruí-lo, com a opção de repreendê-lo ou puni-lo com uma suspensão temporária se necessário.