# Orgulho da Pilha

Tags: debate

Algumas vezes, ao longo desses anos, eu me perguntei *quando* eu escreveria este post, ou *como* eu o faria. Nunca me perguntei *se* eu o faria. Me parecia óbvio que não iria me aposentar, aos 60 e tantos anos, no mesmo emprego que consegui com 28. A vida muda, segue em frente, coisas acontecem ou deixam de acontecer, tudo se transforma, então qual a chance de eu continuar no mesmo emprego por quase 40 anos? É óbvio que esse texto viria.

Não significa que eu sei o que fazer agora que chegou.

A partir do dia 02 de outubro eu não serei mais o Gerente de Comunidades do SOpt, ou sequer um Gerente de Comunidades. Vou ser o mais novo (e único) Customer Success Engineer do [Stack Overflow Enterprise](https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/enterprise). Não tem muito a ver com o que eu fiz durante todo esse tempo, exceto que também não sei direito o que vai acontecer.

Não fazia ideia do que significa ser um "Gerente de Comunidades" quando me candidatei ao cargo. Sabia apenas que o cargo não exigia experiência, e eu não tinha nenhuma para oferecer: a combinação perfeita! É bem fácil perceber, principalmente se você está aqui desde o começo, eu não estou mentindo. Sem querer ter a presunção de que hoje eu sei exatamente o que significa ser um CM, na época eu **realmente** não fazia ideia do que estava fazendo.

"Ótimo!" diriam centenas de gurus de auto-ajuda, seguido de alguma coisa sobre desafios e o desconhecido. E sim... foi ótimo. Nunca aprendi tanto, nunca fiz tanto, nunca me virei tanto, nunca estive tão investido em algo que realmente importasse. Cada centímetro, cada byte, desse site tem, pelo menos, um dedinho de nada meu. Porque vocês iriam perceber, caso não houvesse.

Eu levo orgulho do meu tempo como CM. Orgulho de ter participado da internacionalização de um projeto enorme e significativo; orgulho de ter ajudado a moldar a comunidade, e ter ajudado a comunidade a se moldar; orgulho de ter espalhado o SOpt por aí; orgulho de ver o excelente resultado de todo o trabalho.

Levo orgulho, mas não levo crédito. O crédito **mesmo**, o crédito pelas 105.609 perguntas e pelas 118.494 respostas; pelas 231.253 edições e 101.124 análises. O crédito pelos 497.510 upvotes e downvotes é **inteiramente de vocês**.

Nenhuma das 64.004 pessoas nesse site criou uma conta por minha causa. Criaram para aprender uns com os outros, para dividir o que sabem, para participar da maior comunidade de programação em língua portuguesa. Vocês criaram seus perfis por causa uns dos outros.

Se tenho tanto orgulho, é porque tive a oportunidade de "tomar conta" desse site e porque tive o prazer de ajudar vocês da melhor, maneira que pude. Nem sempre perfeito, nem sempre bonito, mas o trabalho que vou lembrar pra sempre.

Obrigado a todos vocês que tornaram meu emprego um prazer (e um inferno!) todos esses anos. Espero ter ajudado vocês, direta ou indiretamente, tanto quanto gosto de pensar que ajudei. Com todos os poréns, todos os percalços, todos os vacilos e confusões, acho que foram bons anos. É **muito** difícil me acostumar com a ideia de não tomar mais conta desse canto, mas ver o sucesso de vocês torna tudo bem mais fácil.

Eu sabia que teria que escrever esse post um dia, mas não significa que eu estava preparado pra quando a hora chegasse. Mas não esperava outra coisa. Vocês me deram a oportunidade de encarar um desconhecido atrás do outro, sem saber o que fazer, pra onde ir, tendo que me virar do jeito que desse e nada mais justo que o fim da minha participação como CM ocorra dessa forma.

Meu [primeiro post](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1) no Meta foi cuidadosamente escrito à 4 mãos, em 2 línguas, ao longo de semanas. Este último (que não é o último) foi escrito sem preparo, honesto, aberto, e dando o melhor que eu pude. Acho assim mais adequado à minha história aqui. Acho assim mais bonito.

Obrigado, pessoal. Obrigado por tudo.
- Gabe

ps: Eu não sou mais CM, mas meu diamante continua. ***Comportem-se***.

### [image: flwvlwz]

## E agora?

O plano continua! O plano é continuar fazendo o SOpt crescer e amadurecer. Eu saio, mas vocês são os grandes responsáveis pelo site e nada muda aí.

No futuro próximo o [Juan](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/26473) será responsável por manter o circo na estrada e vocês verão mais dele por aqui. Perdoem o portunhol! Além disso o [JNat](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/23291) vai continuar dando uma força, para vocês continuarem podendo reclamar em português!

E bola pra frente. Um novo CM será contratado assim que possível, os planos para o ano que vem continuam valendo: mais camisetas, mais conferências, mais adesivos, mais encontros. Quem me substituir vai ter bastante trabalho pela frente, e espero que se divirta tanto quanto eu.

O SOpt vai continuar crescendo, e se destacando dentro do Stack. Um bom tempo atrás, durante uma reunião, eu disse que nós (e os outros sites internacionais) éramos "inevitáveis". Nós somos o futuro do crescimento do Stack. Pode não ser possível investir tanto nisso agora, mas vocês são o futuro. Inevitavelmente.

Continuem nesse caminho, continuem participando e se divertindo. Vocês são a força-motriz.

Comment: Eu tenho muito orgulho de você Gabe!!!

Comment: Sensacional trabalho Gabe! <3 Sucesso e mais sucesso pra ti. =D Agradecemos por toda paciência e pela colaboração ao Estouro de Pilha. Vlw

Comment: Agora que eu estava a começar a gostar de ti :P

Comment: Mesmo que você não responda meus email, estou feliz por você. kkkkk

Comment: Nem vem @Gabe, você ainda tá me devendo os meus adesivos. Enquanto eles não chegarem você não estará liberado de ser CM (apesar de achar que eles nunca chegarão) kkkkkk

Comment: conferências e encontros :D

Comment: @Francisco Os últimos dias foram meio caóticos, como você pode imaginar! Calma que a resposta vai chegar

Comment: @Stormwind Os adesivos estão sendo enviados em levas, sempre que possível. Mas com os Correios em greve.........

Comment: Irei me comportar e aplicar o que aprendi em convívio com a comunidade, desejo-lhe muito sucesso e que *o seu mal humor possa ir embora* XD ... Um abraço de alguém que lhe admira (mesmo que isto pareça uma surpresa). o/

Comment: Bom @Gabe, não tem problema, posso esperar. Mas enquanto eles não chegarem, você não será liberado de ser CM do [pt.so] :D

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento é mau humor e não mal humor: [Qual é a diferença entre mau e mal?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8/153)

Comment: @JorgeB. pra não perder o *ábito*. :D

Comment: *Sabia apenas que o cargo não exigia experiência, e eu não tinha nenhuma para oferecer: a combinação perfeita!* - #ContrataEu sô XD

Comment: @EMBarbosa saber escrever em português deve ser um dos requisitos #ContrataMe :D

Comment: @JorgeB. , Inglêiz eu não sei, maiz heim portuguêiz eu çôu fera. ;)

Comment: Parabéns @Gabe!!! Seu trabalho sempre será lembrado. Que estourem pilhas de sucesso em seu novo job!

Comment: avante garoto!!!

Comment: Parabéns!!! Sucesso, obrigado por essa comunidade incrível!

Comment: Boa sorte na nova empreitada, Gabe! =]

Comment: Parabéns, cara! Sucesso!

Comment: Parabéns e Sucesso!!! Obs. Aqui vale o comentário repetido :P

Answer (score 17):

Me gustaría agradecerle a Gabe por el tiempo que le dedicó a esta comunidad - la primera de nuestra red internacional. Gabe empezó algo que permitió que la empresa se diera cuenta de la realidad del talento que existe en el mundo entero, no solamente del que viene de países donde se habla inglés. Habemos muchos que con dificultad manejamos ese idioma pero con la oportunidad de convivir con gente que habla nuestra lengua, el aprendizaje sube a un punto extremo.  Ahí nos encontramos hoy.

Tenemos esta comunidad que ha forjado el camino para que las otras comunidades internacionales puedan existir. Y ahora, se presenta la oportunidad de empezar otro capitulo en la historia de SOpt. Es con este entusiasmo que les invito a no dejar de soñar sobre un lugar en donde la información y las amistades se pueden formar y compartir completamente en portugués.  Esta es su comunidad y queremos seguir apoyando su crecimiento y su alcance.

Mi nombre es Juan M y soy el gerente de los Community Managers de Stack Overflow.  Llevo más de una década creando, manteniendo, y reavivando comunidades como esta.  Soy el CM de [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) y mi pasión se encuentra en poder proveerles un lugar donde puedan aumentar su conocimiento y sus amistades en cuanto a la informática. Mi labor en los siguientes meses en cuanto a su comunidad será el de un intermediario.  Trabajaré muy cerca con los moderadores del sitio para planear el futuro de la comunidad. Juntos investigaremos las mejores maneras de crecer y seguir proveyendo la mejor experiencia que podamos para ustedes, nuestros miembros, y los que nos visiten.

Por ahora, no esperen ver cambios radicales. Todo seguirá tranquilo y en orden.  Cómo mencionó Gabe, estaremos en proceso de buscar un Community Manager para este sitio muy pronto.  Necesito preparar el listado de vacantes y me imagino que tendremos a varios que apliquen para esta posición. Les advierto que esto puede tomar un tiempo largo así que necesitaré que sean pacientes mientras traemos a la persona que pueda llevar a esta comunidad a un futuro brillante.

Con eso, me despido de Gabe y le agradezco públicamente por su empeño y energía al dirigir a esta comunidad por los últimos cuatro años.

¡Te vamos a extrañar!

**Disclaimer:** In the spirit of all things international, I thought it would be better to post this in Spanish instead of English. Below is the English translation.

> I would like to thank Gabe for the time he dedicated to this community
>   - the first of our international network. Gabe started something that allowed 
>   the company to realize the reality of the talent that exists
>   in the whole world, not only from countries where
>   English is spoken. There are many of us who can handle English, with some 
>   difficulty, but with the opportunity to come alongside people who speak our
>   language, learning rises to an extreme. This is where we are today.
>
> We have this community which has paved the way for other international
>   communities to exist. And now, we have the opportunity to start
>   another chapter in the history of SOpt. It is with this enthusiasm
>   that I invite you to not stop dreaming about a place where information
>   and friendships can be formed and shared completely in Portuguese.
>   This is your community and we want to continue to support your growth
>   and reach.
>
> My name is Juan M and I am the manager of the Community Managers of
>   Stack Overflow. I've been creating, maintaining, and reviving
>   communities like this for more than a decade. I am the CM of [SOes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) and
>   my passion is to be able to provide a place where you can
>   increase knowledge and friendships in computer science. My
>   work in the following months concerning your community will be that of an
>   liaison. I will work closely with the site moderators to plan the
>   future of your community. Together we will investigate the best ways to
>   grow and continue to provide the best experience we can for you, our
>   members, and those who visit us.
>
> For now, do not expect radical changes. Everything will remain calm
>   and orderly. As Gabe mentioned, we will be in the process of finding
>   a Community Manager for this site very soon. I need to prepare the
>   job listing and I imagine we will have several that apply for
>   this position. I warn you that this may take a long time so I will
>   need you to be patient as we bring the person who can lead this
>   community into a brighter future.
>
> With that, I say goodbye to Gabe and thank him publicly for his
>   commitment and energy in leading this community for the last four
>   years.
>
> We are going to miss you!

Comment: Do you speak english? I do not know the reason you wrote in Spanish, but in English it would make it easier. PS: brasil speak Portuguese and not Spanish. :) Thanks

Comment: In the spirit of all things international, I thought it would be better to post in Spanish. I did delete a disclaimer stating this reason and now I know I should have left it instead.  I'll add it now.  But yes, I'm aware that Brazilians (as well as our friends from Portugal) speak Portuguese.

Comment: I hope that you don't forget the people of Portugal ;) We have to organize a meeting here again.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Não sei se inglês "torna a coisa mais simples". Para quem não domina o inglês, o castelhano poderá ser mais fácil de entender(falo com português, não sei se os brasileiros têm a mesma facilidade em entender o castelhano). É claro que o ideal seria em português.

Comment: @ramaral em uma comunidade de programadores acho mais comum e fácil entenderem inglês que castelhano, o comparativo era apenas entre estes, não sugeri português porque presumi que ele não tivesse "pratica" :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento. Sim, mas sabemos que alguns(muitos?) dos usuários aqui não dominam o inglês. Apenas quis salientar que, talvez, o castelhano fosse entendível por um maior número de pessoas.

Comment: @ramaral não posso negar que seja uma possibilidade, mas realmente pelo menos entre as pessoas que conheço principalmente na área de programação, não conheço ninguém que tenha o minimo de entendimento do castelhano, talvez entre portugueses seja mais comum, mas como é uma questão regional não posso afirmar.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Falei como português. Nós temos facilidade em entender o castelhano. Penso que o que levou o Juan a usar o castelhano foi o facto de ele ser muito parecido com o português.

Comment: @ramaral do meu ponto de vista isso é muito relativo e o uso do castelhano presumindo que seja semelhante pode levar a muitas confusões no entendimento (opinião pessoal apenas). Pela compreensão do idioma semelhante ser algo relativo (creio eu) no final a maioria vai apelar para ferramentas de tradução. Mas acho que não podemos afirmar nada e nem descartar nada.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento O que eu estou tentando dizer é que para quem domina mal o inglês, seria melhor o castelhano, no entanto, aceito que possa estar enganado.

Comment: @ramaral Como disse, é relativo, pode ser errado pra alguns pode ser certo para outros. Você pensa semelhante a mim, só que eu presumi que o inglês seria mais fácil pois é comum na área de TI ter alguma (mesmo que minima) pratica com este idioma, mas é como eu disse, deve ser algo totalmente relativo. Por exemplo eu olho castelhano e até consigo presumir algumas coisas, mas sempre me confundo no entendimento, acho que a postagem ficou boa como esta, inglês e castelhano :)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Sabe o que eu penso agora? Teria sido mais proveitoso se o tempo gasto nesta nossa conversa tivesse sido usado a traduzir a resposta para português :)

Comment: @ramaral concordo e discordo, acho que deveríamos traduzir sim mas também penso que nossa conversa foi muito proveitosa para mim e para ti e para qualquer um que ler e talvez refletir sobre essa questão de idiomas na nossa comunidade :)

Comment: In the future, all announcements from me will be in English and will likely be translated to Portuguese by someone other than me.  I wanted to share in Spanish first to show the importance of our languages and our global mission.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

Acho que esta publicação merece uma resposta e não só um comentário.

Como bem sabes nem sempre estivemos de acordo, alias, acho que fui um dos que mais te deu dores de cabeça por aqui (desculpe qualquer coisa eheheh) mas é o que acontece quando se *comanda as tropas* tem de se lidar com a adversidade... E nesse aspecto tu soubeste quase sempre lidar bem com a adversidade.

Não posso deixar de me lembrar de toda a discussão à volta do SUpt (deve-te ter nascido alguns cabelos brancos por causa disso eheheh) que apesar de não estarmos de acordo em muitos ponto tu sempre soubeste falar com todas as pessoas e até por alguma água na fervura(não sei se conhecem a expressão).

Pode parecer exagerado, mas eu cresci muito enquanto pessoa aqui. Era um noob presunçoso quando aqui cheguei, comecei logo com uma [publicação polêmica](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1157/7210) e esta comunidade ajudou-me bastante a ser mais paciente... E tu ajudaste-me a perceber que um líder tem mesmo de ser assim, forte na tomada de posição e ao mesmo tempo paciente com a posição dos outros e sobretudo com o nervosismo dos outros que pode deixar qualquer um de cabelos em pé...

Por último resta-me agradecer por tudo. Obrigado por tudo e boa sorte na tua nova etapa.

PS: E não te esqueças de escrever em português como deve ser. ;)

Comment: Obrigado, Jorge. Pode ter certeza de que pelo menos um dos meus primeiros cabelos brancos é certamente responsabilidade sua  Brincadeiras a parte, agradeço muito os elogios. Tudo que eu sempre quis aqui foi manter um ambiente de respeito mútuo entre todos, honesto e aberto. Bom saber que, mesmo nos momentos mais complicados, eu atingi pelo menos um pouco disso.

Answer (score 9):

No mesmo espírito do [@Jorge B](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7210/jorge-b) eu acredito que sua pergunta mereça uma resposta:

> I wish you all the success in the world. Engineer on that, punk!

Brincadeiras à parte, é sempre inspirador ver o sucesso do pessoal do Beta e primórdios do Stack Overflow. Ando afastado do SOpt mas de vez em quando passo aqui para responder alguma pergunta aleatória e ver como a galera está. Para mim isso é sempre uma injeção de ânimo.

Falando nesse pessoal, tenho uma recordação muito grata do primeiro evento da Stack Overflow em Português. Se não me falha a memória isso foi em 2014 e ainda estávamos no Beta Público. Havia uma barraquinha do SOpt no [TDC](http://www.thedevelopersconference.com.br). Após o evento tivemos uma confraternização em um *Pub* lá por perto com direito a um *round* de cerveja paga pelo Joel Spolsky e a exímia companhia da galera abaixo:

[image: Evento SOpt 2014]

Para quem não conhece os meliantes para além dos avatares, da esquerda para direita temos: [**utluiz**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/227/utluiz), [**bfavaretto**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto), [**Gabe**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe), a esposa do Math, minha esposa Sigrid (desculpe o clube do bolinha), [**Fat-Tony-With-Lasers**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/100/anthony-accioly), [**Cigano**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/2999/cigano-morrison-mendez), [**Math**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/3117/math) e ???? (se alguém sabe quem é por favor edite; se alguém não quiser ser identificado edite também :D).

De fato, não só sou testemunha ocular, me considero cúmplice direto do "Não sei bem o que estou fazendo mas vamos que vai dar certo". 
Isso vai soar clichê mas naquela época realmente eramos jovens, ingênuos e sonhadores. Lembro que antes do encontro estávamos todos no TDC trocando figurinhas sobre como o SOpt seria ou deixaria de ser: Alguns palpites estavam corretos, outros errados... Nada disso realmente importa, o que importa é que estávamos lá. 
Em algum momento você e eu deixamos o grupo e fomos almoçar em uma Temakeria. Você passou uns 10 minutos me explicando sobre como comer era um ato fisiológico, que para ti isso não era assim tão importante, que um *shake* por dia seria suficiente, etc. Enquanto isso eu saboreava o segundo Temaki especial pensando no que comeria de sobremesa hehehe. 
Em algum momento também discutimos como morar fora seria ou deixaria de ser... Nessa época ainda não precisávamos de vôos intercontinentais para nos reunir, mas a ideia já estava plantada.

O SOpt e tudo o que veio depois dele para mim estão embrulhados no mesmo pacote. Foi um período em que a vontade de fazer esteve em primeiro lugar, todo o resto foi consequência.

Essa "certeza" de que as coisas dariam certo pode soar como pura bravata; em boa parte foi isso mesmo... Mas também foi o combustível da mudança! Foi o que fez esse site ir para frente, e, diretamente ou indiretamente, foi o catalizador que fez com que as nossas carreiras e vidas deslanchassem. Tudo começa com um pouco de cara de pau, com um friozinho na barriga e aquela pergunta crítica que todo mundo um dia se fez: - Tem um lugarzinho aí para mim?

O SOpt foi e é o seu lugar Gabe. Lugar também do pessoal do Beta e dos milhares de usuários que contribuíram e contribuem para o SOpt todos os dias.

É claro que, enquanto a vida move adiante, ninguém aqui vai evaporar (Bem, nunca diga nunca, mas me considero uma presença bastante sólida... :D). Dito isso, desejo que a geração N + 1 do SOpt - incluindo o novo CM, novos moderadores e novos usuários - continue esse excelente trabalho. Que possamos ter um post "Orgulho da Pilha" em 2027. Aproveito também para já lançar a campanha Gabe para presidente do Conselho Intergalático do SO.

Comment: Me lembro dessa foto, na altura eu não reconhecia ninguém, hoje em dia se visse na rua cumprimentava todo mundo. :) Gabe para presidente do Conselho Intergalático do SO. :D

Comment: Hahaha minha cara de "esse negócio vai me dar um trabalho...."

Comment: Agradeço, Anthony. Nem lembrava da nossa conversa sobre Soylent! Eu nunca teria adivinhado tudo que aconteceu desde o dia em que essa foto foi tirada. Eu esperava fortes emoções, mas de lá pra cá eu tive mais alegrias do que achei que fosse ter, mais raiva do que achei que fosse passar, mais orgulho e mais frustrações do que conseguia imaginar na época. Acho que isso é a marca do quão importante essa coisa toda foi, e continua sendo, pra mim. Obrigado pelas memórias.

Comment: Hahahaha. Memórias que ficam na cabeça sem sabermos o motivo. E aí, você foi em frente com o negócio do Soylent?  (OK, melhor tratar disso em outro canal). Espero que tudo isso seja só o começo. E vamos ver se em 2018 reunimos a gangue de novo, quem sabe aí no USA (Se eu voar para Jersey o senhor @utluiz e o Cigano estão intimados a fazer o mesmo).

Answer (score 5):

Esta é minha primeira resposta aqui no meta onde na maior parte do tempo minha presença é passiva.

A pouco mais de três anos criei minha conta no site internacional e somente mais de um ano depois no site em português. Confesso que no começo foi um choque devido a diferença de postura e comportamento da comunidade entre eles, mas rapidamente tomei gosto e quando me dei conta estava focado somente no SOpt, devido a qualidade de conteúdo, por ter pessoas muito boas por aqui e conteúdo de muita qualidade. Sou fã da rede e tenho um carinho especial por ela e pelo o que nos proporciona, afinal quem nunca?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A algumas semanas vim para NYC estudar e despretensiosamente (nem tanto assim rs) tomei a liberdade de convidar @Gabe para almoçar - liberdade que senti ao observar em como ele sempre se mostrou próximo dos membros e da nossa comunidade. É muito legal os encontros marcados nos eventos no Brasil e a sua atenção nos diversos assuntos referente ao site. A surpresa aconteceu quando ele me disse que poderíamos almoçar no escritório do stack em Manhattan e claro que eu adorei a idéia. Pra mim foi um momento muito gratificante da minha carreira conhecer o escritório da comunidade que tenho uma grande admiração, chegar lá e ser muito bem recebido (eles tem um sistema para visitantes bem na entrada do escritório) e sair com um sentimento de realização - além de brindes! Recomendo à todos caso tenham a mesma chance =]

Sempre notei a sua forma profissional em gerenciar a comunidade @Gabe, educação e jogo de cintura ao lidar com assunto as vezes delicados, e acho que esses foram pontos à favor para me tornar mais ativo, pois vi muitos membros - inclusive da parte gerencial e moderação - unidos para fazer o site crescer, e quero estar fazendo parte disso mesmo com pequenas contribuições.

Deixo publicamente meus agradecimentos e desejo boa sorte pra você, obrigado!

Comment: Gostaria de saber mais da sua opinião sobre diferenças de postura entre as comunidades.

Comment: Minha opinião: pessoal por la é mais direto ou seco, porém generalizando são educados. No SOpt deparei com usuários que confundem sarcasmo e ironia e as vezes até falta de educação com ser direto também, mas não demorou muito pra notar que assim como no site internacional, não são todos os usuários, mas somente alguns.

Comment: Concordo com você, por isso prefiro lá nesse ponto. Eu tinha bem menos problemas quando participava em inglês no SE.SE, e meu inglês é ruim. Aqui o que eu digo vive gerando confusão. O pessoal não gosta de crítica, de comparação, de ser direto, tem que ficar passando a mão na cabeça, pegando na mão pra fazer tudo. Claro que é generalização, nem todos são iguais.

Comment: Justamente. Aprendi também com essa diferença entre os dois e me adaptei, no começo chequei aqui com a mesma postura que tinha lá, precisei me adaptar um pouco e sinto que valeu a pena. O site quem faz somos nós, usuários mais experientes me fizeram acreditar que podemos torná-lo sempre melhor.