# Bota-fora SOpt: O que vocês querem saber?

Tags: debate, assembleia-overflow

Essa sexta-feira, 29/09/2017, será meu [último dia como Gerente de Comunidades no SO](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6351).

Queria fazer algo para marcar a data, mas fui informado de que não posso tirar o site do ar... Então acho que a segunda melhor coisa seria uma espécie de [Assembleia Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6154), mas por vídeo e um pouco mais informal.

Minha ideia é criar um hangout público, comigo e mais alguns dos mods, e tirar uma hora para conversar sobre o site, tudo que aconteceu ao longo dos anos e o que vai acontecer nessa era pós-primeiro-CM.

Dependendo das restrições do Hangout (que ainda não pesquisei), talvez ele seja totalmente aberto para que mais pessoas possam se juntar à chamada e conversar diretamente com o resto do pessoal.

As perguntas, assim como na Assembleia, viriam de uma sala de chat separada e seriam respondidas por mim, da melhor maneira possível.

Qualquer assunto... desde por que sua pergunta foi fechada, até o SUpt. Nada é fora de escopo.

**O que**: Chat bota-fora do Gabe
**Quando**: 28/09/2017 - [18:30 BRT | 22:30 WEST | 21:30 UTC](https://doodle.com/poll/caz8hcm27chuac2z)
**Atenção**: Horário sujeito a mudança se necessário
**Onde**: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPj7aw2M65I), com [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66341)!

O que acham?

Comment: O Hangouts so suporta 10 pessoas no video, use o [Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv) ou o [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/live_dashboard_splash).

Comment: Estou dentro Gabe, só anuncie o canal.

Comment: Vamos nessa Vanessa!

Comment: Durante o horário de trabalho é ruim para mim, ideal que fosse tipo 18:30 BRT, mas que seja o horário que for melhor para a maioria

Comment: Mas a gente não quer botar você pra fora Gabe... o.o''

Comment: @Omni boa(s) idea(s). Vou dar uma olhada e decidir melhor. Obrigado pela dica

Comment: @EMBarbosa Pra ser sincero, eu recomendo me botar pra fora, trancar a porta, e chamar a polícia 

Comment: @Math adicionei uma enquete pra saber qual o melhor horário pra todo mundo

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOO eu achava que o chat seria hoje, Sexta! =/

Comment: @OnoSendai NOOOOOOOOO! Eu até falei de você! E tá gravado :D

Comment: @Gabe https://youtu.be/g0ffCICQ-bU?t=1m53s

Comment: faça uma live pelo youtube @Gabe

Comment: Poxa só vi agora a postagem, rolou mesmo o debate, vai ter outro?