# Vamos ser proativos no Stack Overflow em Português!

Tags: debate

Muito obrigado a [@hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/112052/hkotsubo) pela tradução.

---

#### O Problema

Tenho a impressão de que o Stack Overflow em Português está mais distante do Time de *Community Growth*, se comparado às outras comunidades internacionais, e as iniciativas trazidas "de fora" são percebidas pela comunidade com um certo ceticismo. Parece-me que isso não está tão relacionado com as iniciativas em si, mas com a forma como elas são apresentadas (sim, estou falando de "diferenças culturais"). Como resultado, muitas iniciativas que têm beneficiado outras comunidades por anos são completamente desconsideradas no Stack Overflow em Português. *A comunidade não consegue ter o ímpeto de crescimento que precisa*.

#### Proposta de Solução

O Time de *Community Growth* quer ajudar a fazer do Stack Overflow em Português um site ainda mais bem sucedido. Para isso, a comunidade precisa ter o ímpeto de crescimento correto. Sendo sincero, como eu dificilmente poderei aprender com rapidez a cultura do Stack Overflow em Português (mas vou tentar!), achamos que o único caminho possível é trabalhar ainda mais próximo dos usuários mais ativos da comunidade.

Estou procurando por "ativistas" na comunidade, pessoas que trabalharão conosco para se tornar a força motriz do crescimento proativo da comunidade.

#### Quem é um "ativista"?

Um ativista é qualquer pessoa que queira melhorar algo na comunidade. Ativismo não está ligado à reputação, nem ao *status* de moderador. É uma iniciativa pessoal de cada usuário.

#### Como se tornar um ativista?

Não é preciso se inscrever. Apenas ajude sua comunidade a crescer diariamente: acompanhe os problemas da comunidade, participe das discussões no meta, sugira iniciativas que você ache interessantes. Temos que derrubar a "barreira das diferenças culturais" entre a empresa e a comunidade:

- Por favor me digam se você é uma dessas pessoas proativas que querem que a comunidade cresça, fazendo uma das seguintes ações:

  - Escreva uma resposta para esta pergunta.
  - Faça uma menção a mim na sala de chat [The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal).
  - Envie-me um email ([contatos no meu perfil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/17539/nicolas-chabanovsky?tab=profile)).

  Quando eu vir uma iniciativa que pode ajudar a comunidade, antes de mais nada, entrarei em contato no [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal) com os usuários que são proativos na comunidade e que desejem dar um *feedback*. Ao me contactar por um desses meios, saberei com quem entrar em contato.
- *Sugira iniciativas no meta que são interessantes para você*. Siga [esta discussão no MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317206/274323), traga para a comunidade as melhores práticas dos outros sites da rede Stack Exchange.
- Se você acha que eu posso ajudá-lo com uma iniciativa que você quer que a comunidade tenha, *por favor me diga (por exemplo, [no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal))*. Pode ser análise de dados, mudança de configurações do site ou *feedback* baseado na experiência de outras comunidades.
- *Seja proativo com as iniciativas de outros usuários no meta*. Não fique indiferente, compartilhe suas ideias e opiniões, elas ajudarão a fazer um site melhor.
- *Junte-se à sala de chat [The Terminal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84778/the-terminal)*. Neste chat você descobrirá o que está acontecendo nas outras comunidades internacionais.

Vamos juntos melhorar continuamente o Stack Overflow em Português, para todos os colegas e para nós mesmos. Vamos ser proativos e nos manter mais próximos.

Comment: I think the site has a lot to grow and main premise that I think is very important is: help those who need it

Comment: Uma iniciativa interessante que facilitaria o processo seria a SE contratar novamente um CM que fale português. Isso diminuiria bastante a distância entre a comunidade e o tal "time de Community Growth". (*English version: An interesting initiative that would facilitate the process would be to hire a CM who speaks Portuguese again. This would greatly reduce the distance between the community and the  "Community Growth team"*)

Comment: Nicolas, digo isso porque por mais que você esteja se dedicando para dar conta das comunidades internacionais você mesmo assume que o fator idioma limita muita coisa. Já se passou [mais de um ano](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6381/5878) que o [Gabe](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/12/gabe) deixou o cargo de CM e desde então a SE não mostrou interesse nenhum em fechar esse buraco. Se é interesse dela e ela reconhece a limitação, o que mais falta para decidir que existe a demanda de um novo CM?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Thank you for the feedback. I do agree that having a dedicated CM for each int'l site would be great. At the same time I personally believe that there is no the right or wrong approach in such situations. We can accomplish the same results using completely different approaches and each of them has pros and cons. Let us discuss wether we want to wait [nobody knows how much time] a new dedicated CM or start thinking how we can grow the site together with the current team.

Comment: I cannot promise that it would be an easy way but I can say that I will do my best to make Stack Overflow in Portuguese the best community of professional and enthusiast programmers and the best source of knowledge on programming in the Portuguese language. It would be a mistake if I thought that I could do something without your and the others folks' help. I believe that our willingness to create a great community and a good knowledge base matters more than the language we speak.

Comment: It seems [now we do have a new CM who speaks Portuguese](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/326611/announcing-the-arrival-of-valued-associate-679-cesar-manara?cb=1) @AndersonCarlosWoss!

Comment: Can you give concrete examples of what exactly you are talking about? I think it would be easier if we actually had a list of issues to work with instead of a vague description of an issue.

Comment: @BrunoCosta One of the things to start with could be [the answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/317206/274323) that contains lists of problems, findings and initiatives for each site. Please go though the initiative section and pick any from the ones that are presented on other international sites but not on SOpt. On the other hand if you see a problem in the SOpt community, please ask a question on MSOpt, add it to the list of problems and ping me. Together we will find a working solution.

Answer (score -1):

Entendo que o idioma é uma fator de dificuldade e a parte cultural também, mudar a postura em reação aos fatos tudo bem, mas aqui no Brasil nem sempre isso é tão simples, poucos desenvolvedores nos projetos, falta de tempo, tudo isso impacta nas entregas e dificulta ser proativo na comunidade quando temos que também ser proativo com nossos empregadores.